# Magento getProductCount() on subcategory

Tags: magento, categories

the getProductCount() in the second level of category echo count print out 0, i try different way but i diddn't figure out like mage get collection etc, i didn'd find any solution at this question

```
  <?php
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->entity_id);
$helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
?>
  <?php foreach ($collection as $cat):?>

  <?php 
  $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
  $_img = $cur_category->getThumbnailUrl();
  ?>
  <div class="grid_4">
<div class="mineContent_grid_4">

 <dl>
  <dt>
    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat);?>">
        <?php echo $cat->getName();?>
        <img src="<?php echo $_img?>" title="<?php echo $cat->getName();?>" width="173" height="208"/>
    </a>
  </dt>    
    <?php $childLevel2Category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($cat->entity_id);
    ?>
    <dd>
        <ol>
          <?php foreach ($childLevel2Category as $catLevel2) { ?>
          <?php
           $cur_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
           $count = $cur_category2->getProductCount();
          ?>

          <li> <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($catLevel2);?>"><?php echo $catLevel2->getName();?> <span>(<?php echo $count ?>)</span></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ol>
    </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
</div>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have this code:

```
<?php
   $cur_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
   $count = $cur_category2->getProductCount();
?>
```

This loads `$cur_category2` with `$cat->getId()`, which is your parent category and not the current category. I think you want this:

```
<?php
   $cur_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catLevel2->getId());
   $count = $cur_category2->getProductCount();
?>
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If that solved your problem, select my answer as the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that should help you. All my snippet does is get the product count for the category. I hard coded a category ID of 4, but your code should work, getting the current category. You may want to isolate this code into a function to keep it simpler, then just reference it from your existing page. It essentially loads a collection of products, by category, filtering out products that aren't visible.

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($_category);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

echo $collection->count();
```

Comment: Why is someone downvoting 4 years after the post?

Answer (score -1):

try this example

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2)->getChildrenCategories();
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addCountToCategories($categories);

var_dump($categories);
```

where 2 - category id
also check php class **Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation** in Magento